# What does this code do? (Java Collection)

Tags: java, collections

I have been learning "Thinking in Java". I have found this code:

```
class SetType {
  int i;
  public SetType(int n) { i = n; }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof SetType && (i == ((SetType)o).i);
  }
  public String toString() { return Integer.toString(i); }
}
```

I cannot understand what this does:

```
i == ((SetType)o).i
```

I understood that `Object o` is cast to `SetType`, but that about ".i" ?
If anyone understand that is it mean in will be good.

Comment: What does the book say it does?

Comment: That is just accessing the `i` member of a SetType object, which is the result of casting `o`.

Comment: Throw the book away. The field `i` should have a more descriptive name and should probably be private. Plus they make the unforgivable mistake of overriding `equals()` but not `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

> ```
>   public boolean equals(Object o) {
>     return o instanceof SetType && (i == ((SetType)o).i);
>   }
> ```

Is a shorter form of this equivalent way of writing the same thing:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof SetType) {
        SetType other = (SetType) o;
        if (i == other.i) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I hope you'll find this easier to understand. You can simplify this code to reach the original. They are equivalent.

Comment: Now I understood. But is this short form normal style of programming?

Comment: It's pretty common, yes. You get used to it over time. There are also unnecessary parentheses in the original, this would be enough: `return o instanceof SetType && (i == ((SetType)o).i);` Some IDE can simplify expressions automatically for you into this form (for example IntelliJ)

Answer (score 3):

It accesses the "i" field of the instance of the SetType class.

Answer (score 2):

The `.i` is accessing the member variable `i` of that object.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to understand here is that two things are done in one expression. First object `o` is cast into an object of class `SetType`, this is the `(SetType)o` part, then the field `i` of this object is accessed. It might help to think of this as the following two steps

```
SetType s = (SetType)o;
s.i;
```

Note that the cast is safe, because you test `o instanceof SetType` first, and that the cast is also necessary, as `o` is an instance of class `Object` and thus doesn't have a field named `i`, i.e., `o.i` would not work. For completeness, here's a fully "expanded" version of your code:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof SetType) {
    SetType s = (SetType)o;
    return (i == s.i);
  }
  return false;
}
```